# AngularJS : ng-if and ng-repeat not working after custom transclusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I am attempting to do custom transclusion of a directive in angularJS as I need to transclude two separate elements into two separate locations.

The issue is that whilst some directives carried over on the transcluded content work such as `ng-bind` others such as `ng-if` or `ng-repeat` do not, even after recompiling the transcluded elements with the correct scope.

Example: http://jsbin.com/menakapoma/1/edit?html,js,output

As you can see in the example the `ng-bind` works but the `ng-if` does not even though they are both on the same scope and accessing the same value. Neither the true or false state of the `ng-if` works.

I believe this is because the `ng-if` directive gets transcluded as a comment, however even if I set the priority of the transcluding directive to `9999` and perform it in the pre-linkage function it still does not work.

Does anyone know how to get these directives working?

Comment: I had a similar issue but was unable to create a fiddle demonstrating my solution. My solution was to first `.append` the clone to the template, and then move the `.contents` of the *container* of the clone rather than the clone itself. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that no matter what by the time the `transclude` function executes the nested directives have already been compiled and replaced with comments.

I have managed to achieve this by completely foregoing the transclude options, and manually requesting the template via `$templateRequest`.

I specify a compile function which replaces the element with a comment placeholder to ensure nothing is rendered during the request.

In the linkage function I manually compile the template and then replace directive's element with it.

See the updated example here: http://jsbin.com/rocedarono/3/edit?html,js,console,output

It certainly doesn't feel like the cleanest/optimal solution and I am open to any other solutions that can do it a little nicer. Especially as any DOM events have to be bound to after the `$templateRequest` promise is resolved and checked for existence before removal on the `$destroy` event to ensure it resolved beforehand.

Comment: Was browsing the site and saw you here..:-)

Comment: @AliGajani Stalker :)

Comment: I have come across with the similar issue, and followed your pattern. You saved me a big time. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, but your example has so many distractions (toggle, tables, wrappers, multiple slots, template requests, etc). It would be really helpful if you simplified your jsbins to have a single `<div>` with `ng-if` and nothing else; one example of it working and the other without.